# Where do I store global configuration for SharePoint Online web part?

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part

We are developing a web part within the company I work in to be used on many SharePoint sites on SharePoint Online. I originally thought of using an XML file stored on a shared site to store hierarchical global web part settings but I am afraid that loading the settings and performance will be impacted.

The storage mechanism must:

- allow the web part to cache the settings
- be really fast i.e. < 1 second to load
- allow for hierarchical settings to be set, similar to XML

Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

You can use tenant properties within your webpart. The properties can be set by an administrator using powershell and can be retrieved using a http request.

See tenant [properties documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/tenant-properties) for examples and usage

Comment: I can see how this would be useful. Could probably store a json string in that property BUT not sure what the max size is.